# XCOPY without the message about how many files were copied?

Tags: xcopy

I want to see messages about which files are being copied using XCOPY, but suppress the final message about how many files were copied ("File(s) copied")

Any idea?

Comment: Okay I have to ask this, but why? What's so bad about that final line that you MUST suppress it? A little context would help here as well.

Comment: I need to copy the file names to some text file to exclude them next time i'm running the script.

Comment: I can't think of any nice ways but the direct approach of piping through `findstr /l /v "File(s) copied"` and hoping that the user doesn't have a localized version of Windows might be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks! its working :)
`xcopy "C:\test "x:\"  /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt | findstr /l /v "File(s) copied" >> "C:\COPY TEST\exclude.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @doynax.
the answer to my question is to pipe

```
findstr /l /v "File(s) copied"
```

to XCOPY